# rsync files-from unable to handle filename with subfolder?

Tags: rsync

I need to sync remotes files to local with the following command:

```
rsync -schavzP --stats --files-from=./filelist.txt -e "ssh -p 22" remoteuser@1.2.3.4:/home/somewhere/ .
```

While filelist.txt contains several subfolder filenames:

```
subfolder/746fbd52ec4441b88f62ead5beb8e57e
subfolder/test
```

The command gives the following error:

```
rsync: link_stat "/home/somewhere/subfolder/746fbd52ec4441b88f62ead5beb8e57e" failed: No such file or directory
```

If I issue rsync without files-from, and give the remote filename directly in command line, it works.

Appreciate if someone could lend me a hand.  Thank you.

Comment: You did verify that the file does exist?

Comment: Yes definitely.  I can rsync the file by command line

Comment: Show the output from `ls -l /home/somewhere/subfolder/746fbd52ec4441b88f62ead5beb8e57e`, copy the path exactly from the error message rsync gives. Run `strace -f -e file rsync ..." and show the line that refers to this file. Append the information to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: @RalfFriedl It lists the file is there.  Nothing special. Thank you for your input.  I found the real cause finally.

Answer (score 1):

As usual it turns out the real cause is not what I think it was.

The "filelist.txt" was an UTF8 textfile which has BOM codes at the beginning of the file as hidden codes.  Even "vi", "vim", "nano" are not able to show them.

Removed all those hidden codes and the above rsync codes inside bash script should work.

Sorry for the chaos.

Comment: Would you please add into your answer how did you delete that BOM characters bytes ?